# angular form submission not checking for validation of form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

When I click submit button, the form gets submitted instead of validating for the required fields.

**Markup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>HTML 5</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p ng-show="msg"> {{ msg }}</p>
        <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="valid()">
            <p> Name <input type="text" name="name" id="" ng-model="user.name" ng-required=true></p>
            <p ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && myForm.name.$touched">name is required</p>
            <p> Email <input type="email" name="email" id="" ng-model="user.email" ng-required=true> </p>
            <p ng-show="myForm.email.$invalid && myForm.email.$touched">must be a valid email</p>

            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('myApp', [])
         .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.valid = function() {
            $scope.msg = "form submitted";
         }
      }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest way to call function if form is validate is dictated below, which will fired up valid `function` only when form is valid.

```
ng-submit="myForm.$valid && valid()"
```

Or other way would be check `myForm` object in `$scope`, because when you give `name="myForm"` on form, angular does create a object inside scope that have all the information field information inside that object.

```
$scope.valid = function(){
   if($scope.myForm.$valid){
      //form is valid
      //do $http.post call if you wanted to submit form data
   }
   else {
      alert('form is invalid');//some how notify user that form is invalid.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put:

```
$scope.valid=function() {
  if ($scope.myForm.isValid()) $scope.msg="form submitted";
  else $scope.msg="form with errors";
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the submit button using:

`ng-disabled="boolean expression"`

in your case it will be simply:

`<input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid">`